# MAP kit pricing [the monthly free quota of US$300,]

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have a question please as it's not clear in the following link https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/about-charging-0000001051637068-V5
the monthly free quota of US$300, means that I'll have each beginning of the month US300$ or just only the first month ?

Comment: This would work better on the SuperUser site, or maybe Quora.

Comment: Every month, but won't accumulate, you must spend all 300 in the same month, or the remainder will be lost and you will get a new 300$ coupon at start of next month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the free quota of US$300 is used up, you need to pay for the extra usage in the current billing cycle.

Also If you have subscribed to a free plan and want to upgrade it to the pay-as-you-go tier, click Upgrade to pay-as-you-go plan in AGC console, read the upgrade notes carefully below, and click OK. The upgrade takes effect immediately.

Link to follow upgrade steps : https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-service-billing#upgrade

You can view your free quota usage in AGC console. To view usage:

Go to Project Settings → My quota → Map Kit